# How to detect collisions for a rotating child object in Unity3D C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, collision, collider

I am making a First Person Shooter and I have a rigged player with a mouse look script, and I used to rotate the spine with spine.transform.rotation, but this method does not look for collisions, this means if I rotate and I am standing near to a GameObject, I glitch/bug through the object. So I tried to do it with a Rigidbody but this doesn't seem to work, I tried: rbSpine.AddTorque(new Vector3(mouseLook.y,0,0), ForceMode.Force);. This doesn't do anything. And I have another problem with the Rigidbody, I've only a rigidbody attached to the spine, my player has multiple simple collision and these overlap eachother a little, and my rigidbody is pushed away into the air slowly. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a rigidbody component on the player, this will take care of the collision detection for itself and all its child objects.